# Does the global variant in different threads means different variants?

Tags: c, pthreads

I tried to translate the `parallel execution of sections` in **OpenMP** into **pthread** program. I use a global variant (`sect_left`) to record the total number of sections to be execute, but it seems that the variant (`sect_left`) in different threads are two different variants and have independent values.

To make my program easier to understand, I have simplified it as shown in the following:

```
#include <pthread.h>

define get_tid() syscall(__NR_gettid)

int sect_left = -1;    //the total number of sections to be execute
int nthr_in_sect = 0;  //the number of threads entered the sections
pthread_mutex_t mt_sect; 

void entering_sections(int numberofsections)
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mt_sect);
  if(nthr_in_sect <= 0){    //if this is the first thread come in
    sect_left = numberofsections;  //set number of sections when first thread come in
    printf("%d set number of sections: %d\n", get_tid(), sect_left);
  }
  nthr_in_sect++;   //the number of threads entered +1
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt_sect);
}

void leaving_sections()
{
  pthread_mutex_lock(&mt_sect);
    nthr_in_sect--;  //the number of threads in sections -1 after leaving sections
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt_sect);
}

int get_section()
{
  if (sect_left < 0) return (-1);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&mt_sect);
    int s = --(sect_left);   //fetch a section and the total number -1
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&mt_sect);

  return (s);
}

static void * func(void *arg)
{
  {
    int caseid = -1;
    entering_sections(2);
    for(;;)
    {
      //if there is no section remain
      if((caseid = get_section()) < 0) break; 

      switch(caseid)
      {
        case 0:
          printf("section 11 threadID = %d\n",get_tid());
          break;
        case 1:
          printf("section 22 threadID = %d\n",get_tid());
          break;
      }
    }
    leaving_sections();
  }
}

void main()
{
  pthread_mutex_init(&mt_sect, NULL);

  pthread_t thr;
  pthread_create(&thr,NULL,func, (void *) 0);

  (*func)((void *) 0);

  pthread_join(thr,NULL);

  pthread_mutex_destroy(&mt_sect);
}
```

> the output of my program is:

[image]

If the global variant in different threads is different variants, **how to represent a global variant that is the only one in the whole program no matter how many threads there are?**

Thank you!

Comment: A global variable exists only once per process BUT concurrent accesses (from multiple threads) have to be guarded. This can be achieved by a mutex. Alternatively, the global variable can be made [atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic). (In opposition, to make a per-thread variable, [`thread_local`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/thread/thread_local) has been introduced.)

Comment: In `get_section` in `func`, you're accessing the global without having locked the mutex.

Comment: I'm not sure but `int s = --(sect_left);` (in `get_section())` does possibly not what you expect. (The parentheses doesn't prevent decrementing of `sect_left`.) To be sure, I tried in [**wandbox**](https://wandbox.org/permlink/RM3O6zIHmbTRnUCD). Thus, `int s = sect_left - 1;` might fix your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think the following is happening:

```
nthr_in_sect == 0
4789: entering_sections(2);
sec_left = 2
4789: print section strings
sec_left = -1
4789: leaving_sections();
nthr_in_sect == 0 (again)
4790: entering_sections(2);
sec_left = 2
4790: print section strings
sec_left = -1
4790: leaving_sections();
nthr_in_sect == 0 (again)
```

So the program functions as written. The first thread just finishes so fast that the second starts all over again because it thinks it is the first.

Maybe you should have separate counters for nthr_entered_sect and nthr_left_sect? Or a boolean flag sec_left_initialized.